# GitLab Ci Runner error " bash: line 21: xcodebuild: command not found "

Tags: ios, linux, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I hava a **gitlab-ci service** on Linux , here is the information

```
Linux DevOps 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 23 15:44:03 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I followed this tutorial https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/ , before the section **How to trigger builds** 
everything worked fine , the only different is the environment which is OS **"El Capitan"** and **"Linux"** .

When I try **git push** then error appear , I have no idea hot to solve this ....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xcodebuild` is only available on OS X, so you need to have to build your application on a host with OS X and XCode installed.

Comment: thx , I will try using OS X service or try install VM on the Ubuntu